# Does pure lanolin for sale in stores still contain vitamins?

Tags: dermatology, micronutrients, oil, hydration, moisturize

I have heard that lanolin is a great source of certain vitamins, particularly vitamin d2 & d3. I like to use lanolin on my skin as a moisturizer, but I'd much rather use it in it's most natural form - preferably before it's been irradiated to remove the vitamins. I can't find any concrete evidence that shows that typical store-bought lanolin does not have it's natural vitamins, but I've noticed that the labels don't mention the vitamin content (which I believe would be a big selling point). If I am correct with my assumption that typical cosmetic lanolin has had its vitamins extracted, does anyone know of a type of lanolin for sale that still has these vitamins in it?

Thank you for your time!